# How to understand the synthetic accessor code generated by jd-gui?

Tags: java, decompiler, jd-gui

All , I was trying to read some code which is generated from the jd-gui. It looks like below.

```
    public class agrPullingAgentStudy
    {
      private static final String PGPR_ID = "agrPullingAgentStudy";
      private static Timer m_tmStudy = null;
      private static Timer m_tmNonStop = null;
      private static Timer m_tmRemove = null;
      private static String m_szManual = "";
      private static String m_szProcRule = "";
      private static String m_szExecHosp = "";
      private static HashMap<String, HashMap> m_hRemoteAll = new HashMap();
      private static HashMap<String, String> m_hProcRule = null;
      private static int m_nImageAfterMins = -120;
      private static boolean m_bDoProcess = false;
      private static Date m_dAliveDT = new Date();
      private static final String LINE_SEP = System.getProperty("line.separator");
    ....



      private class dcmStudySchedule
        extends TimerTask
      {

        public void run()
        {
          String FUN_ID = "runStudySchedule";
          StringBuffer szBuffer = new StringBuffer();
          agrPullingAgentStudy.access$002(new Date());

          ...
        }


       ....
       agrPullingAgentStudy.access$402(agrPullingAgentStudy.m_szExecHosp.substring(0, agrPullingAgentStudy.m_szExecHosp.length() - 1));
       ...
      }
    }
```

The class `agrPullingAgentStudy` include an inner class named dcmStudySchedule. and in the inner class.

What I can not understand is the `access$xxx` which I already knew it is because if the inner class tried to access the outer class members then the generated code will user `access$xxx` to represent this kind of code. I just want to know if there is any workaround to fix this issue. Or How can I understand this code? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following snippet will produce your decompiled source.

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class agrPullingAgentStudy {

    private static Date m_dAliveDT = new Date();

    private class dcmStudySchedule extends TimerTask {

        public void run() {
            m_dAliveDT = new Date();
        }
    }
}
```

To understand the `agrPullingAgentStudy.access$002(new Date())` it's helpful to do some investigation on the bytecode level.

First compile the source `javac agrPullingAgentStudy .java`. It generates two `*.class` files. `agrPullingAgentStudy.class` and `agrPullingAgentStudy$dcmStudySchedule.class`. (ok no surprice till now).

To access the variable `m_dAliveDT` from class `dcmStudySchedule` the compiler generates a synthetic method in `agrPullingAgentStudy`. The signature is `static Date access$002(Date var0)`.

How do come to this conclusion? ... Simple: using `javap`.

```
javap -c -v agrPullingAgentStudy.class
```

reveals the generated bytecode

```
static java.util.Date access$002(java.util.Date);
  descriptor: (Ljava/util/Date;)Ljava/util/Date;
  flags: ACC_STATIC, ACC_SYNTHETIC
  Code:
    stack=2, locals=1, args_size=1
       0: aload_0
       1: dup
       2: putstatic     #1        // Field m_dAliveDT:Ljava/util/Date;
       5: areturn
```

The `#1` refer to the index in the constant pool (will also be shown by the above `javap` command)

```
Constant pool:
   #1 = Fieldref       #5.#21   // agrPullingAgentStudy.m_dAliveDT:Ljava/util/Date;
...
```

As Java source it would look like

```
static Date access$002(Date d) {
    m_dAliveDT = d;               // putstatic #1
    return d;                     // areturn
}
```

Comment: Hi Suboptimal, Thanks your nice explain. As to your example . what does #1 mean in the byte code?  It seems it represent the first member of outer class, What if there are many members in there? How to know which member the #number represents?  thanks.

Comment: @Joe.wang the `#1` refere to the index in the constant pool. To better understand the output of `javap` it might be helpful to read the [Java Virutal Machine Sepecification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/) about the [class File Format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html).

Comment: FYI, Procyon's decompiler should inline synthetic accessors, and its disassembler displays more useful member references than the simple constant pool indexes that javap shows.  CFR also does a nice job with synthetic accessors.

Comment: @MikeStrobel I know. But this was not the question of the OP. ;-) Anyway it make some sence to know about the internals.